# How do I detect "_" in a C++ string?

Tags: c++, string, search, find

I want to know the positions of the "_" in a string:

```
string str("BLA_BLABLA_BLA.txt");
```

Something like:

```
string::iterator it;
for ( it=str.begin() ; it < str.end(); it++ ){
 if (*it == "_")         //this goes wrong: pointer and integer comparison
 {
  pos(1) = it;
 }
 cout << *it << endl;
}
```

Thanks,
André

Comment: Try using single quotes instead of double quotes.

Comment: @Dominic why isn't this an answer?

Comment: @Motti - it is now (see sbi's answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3725574/detect-in-a-string/3725671#3725671)

Answer (score 16):

Note that `"_"` is a ***string literal***, while `'_'` is a ***character literal***.

If you dereference an iterator into a string, what you get is a ***character***. Of course, characters can only be compared to ***character*** literals, not to ***string*** literals.

However, as others have already noticed, you shouldn't implement such an algorithm yourself. It's been done a million times, two of which (`std::string::find()` and `std::find()`) ended up in C++' standard library. Use one of those.

Answer (score 9):

```
std::find(str.begin(), str.end(), '_');
                               // ^Single quote!
```

Answer (score 8):

string::find is your friend.
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

```
someString.find('_');
```

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the [`find`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/) function as:

```
string str = "BLA_BLABLA_BLA.txt";
size_t pos = -1;

while( (pos=str.find("_",pos+1)) != string::npos) {
        cout<<"Found at position "<<pos<<endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Found at position 3
Found at position 10
```

Comment: The answer is wrong. Regardless of whether you provide an initial position or not, the `std::string::find` will return the position *in the string*. The line `pos += found+1` should be changed to `pos = found+1`, and while you are at it, the whole `found` variable can be removed by initializing `pos` to `-1`, passing `pos+1` to `find` and storing the return value in `pos`. Try with "BLA_BLABLA_BLA_BLA.txt", it will only detect the first two '_'.

Answer (score 6):

Why dont you use the find method : http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/